# How to connect to Cloud SQL instance using nodejs and pem keyfile

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-sql, node-mysql

I'm trying to connect to Cloud SQL instance from nodejs application using pem file key.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'root', '', {
    host: '<ip>',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    ssl: {
       ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server-ca.pem'),
       key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert.pem')
    }
});
sequelize.query('select * from Users').then(function (users) {
    console.log(users);
});
```

I got `Possibly unhandled SequelizeAccessDeniedError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'<ip>' (using password: NO)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot give a try to none of the answers at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your ssl options are not correct. You have put a "cert" file in the `key` parameter. Your ssl config should look like:

```
  ssl: {
     ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server-ca.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client-cert.pem'),
     key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client-key.pem')
  }
```

Where client-key.pem is the private key corresponding to client-cert.pem. You should get all three of these files when you follow the [Cloud SQL SSL instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance).

Answer (score 1):

I just looked up a quick google search of `mysql access denied using password no`, and the MySQL docs themselves say that this error message comes when you tried to log in without using a password. (CTRL + F for "you tried to log in without a password"). This is likely to be the source of the issue.

Otherwise, have you followed the instructions from the Cloud SQL docs on [how to connect from an external application](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external)? Specifically, you'll want to ensure that your box's IP or IP range is allowed by your instance. Be aware that if you're behind a firewall that does NAT, a corporate proxy, an open proxy, or any other private proxy you/your ISP owns, you'll need to ensure that the IP of *that* network node is allowed, as your IP packets will appear to originate from there. You can test this by running `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`, which will use an external service to tell you what your IP appears to be.

You may also want to double-check the docs on [TLS and Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance) to ensure everything you've done is good in that regard.